# Agregar un par propiedad:valor en un Objeto desde php

Tags: php, ajax, json, objeto

Tengo una funcion en `php` que retorna un elemento por `ajax` a mi archivo `js` (omitan las variables redundantes, es para hacer pruebas unitarias)

```
    /*===============================================
MOSTRAR VIANDA COMEDOR
===============================================*/

public $idComedor;

public function ajaxMostrarViandaComedor(){


    $item = "id";
    $valor = $this->idComedor;

    $respuesta = ControladorViandas::ctrMostrarViandas($item, $valor);

    $respuesta2 = ModeloViandas::mdlObtenerIngredientes($respuesta["id"]);

    $respuesta3 = json_encode($respuesta2,true);



    echo ($respuesta3);

}
```

Esa funcion me retorna el siguiente elemento a mi archivo `js` :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {0: "11", 1: "1", 2: "200", id_ingrediente: "11", id_vianda: "1", cantidad: "200"}
1: {0: "13", 1: "1", 2: "666", id_ingrediente: "13", id_vianda: "1", cantidad: "666"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

---

Lo que quisiera hacer, es colocar un `foreach` dentro de la funcion `ajaxMostrarViandaComedor` que vaya a la base de datos a buscar un elemento, y que me agregue ciertas partes de ese elemento a mi `$respuesta3` para que quede de la siguiente forma

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
    0: {0: "11", 1: "1", 2: "200",3:"Tomate" id_ingrediente: "11", id_vianda: "1", cantidad: "200", nombre: "Tomate"}
    1: {0: "13", 1: "1", 2: "666", 3: "Carne Picada", id_ingrediente: "13", id_vianda: "1", cantidad: "666", nombre: "Carne Picada"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

> Notese que se agrego una propiedad llamada "nombre" con un valor.

Intente agregar la siguiente estructura entre las lineas `$respuesta3 = json_encode($respuesta2, true);` y `echo($respuesta3)`

```
 foreach($respuesta3 as $value){
            $idIngrediente = $value["id_ingrediente"];
            $item = "id";

            $respuestaIng = ControladorIngredientes::ctrMostrarIngredientes($item, $idIngrediente);

            array_push($value["nombre"], $respuestaIng["nombre"]);
        }
```

> El problema está en la linea `array_push($value["nombre"], $respuestaIng["nombre"]);`, no funciona y entiendo que es porque estoy intentando manipular un objeto y la funcion es para arrays. Yo quisiera en esa linea, agregar una nueva propiedad al objeto, llamada `nombre` y asignarle el valor que viene en `$respuestaIng["nombre"]`, pero no estoy dando con la funcion que necesito.

Estoy haciendo esto porque lo que estaba haciendo antes eran multiples llamadas a `ajax` anidadas, y me dijeron que es una pesima practica, asi que ahora mi intencion es solo dejar una llamada a `ajax` y devolver todo lo que necesito en una unica respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente usa la referencia del array para modificarlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach($respuesta3 as &$value)
{
            $idIngrediente = $value["id_ingrediente"];
            $item = "id";
            $respuestaIng = ControladorIngredientes::ctrMostrarIngredientes($item, $idIngrediente);
            $value["nombre"]=$respuestaIng["nombre"];
}
```

Aquí, al pasar `$value` por referencia mediante `&$value`, vas a tener la posibilidad de modificar el array en sí.

Lo mismo si se tratase de un objeto:

```
foreach($respuesta3 as &$value)
{
            $idIngrediente = $value["id_ingrediente"];
            $item = "id";
            $respuestaIng = ControladorIngredientes::ctrMostrarIngredientes($item, $idIngrediente);
            $value->nombre=$respuestaIng["nombre"];
}
```

Te recomiendo que consultas ***[Pasar por referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php)*** en el Manual de PHP.

Comment: Infinitas gracias :)