# Eliminar registros de array de objetos

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un array de objetos que estoy iterando para buscar los registros que tengan EmailType = INST, obtener su matricula y eliminar los registro que tengan esa matricula.

Les comparto mi código obtengo la matricula, únicamente me falta eliminar los registros que tienen esa matricula. Intente hacer la eliminación con la función unset() de PHP pero no me quedo.
Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Se los agradecería mucho.

> Array

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000096 
    [FIRST_NAME] => JOSE 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => AGUSTIN 
    [a_paterno] => ARELLANO 
    [a_materno] => LOPEZ 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => PERS 
    [email_people] => agustin_arellano@outlook.com ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000269 
    [FIRST_NAME] => LUIS 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => FERNANDO 
    [a_paterno] => BOCANEGRA 
    [a_materno] => RAMIREZ 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => INST 
    [email_people] => lubocanegrara@ucq.edu.mx ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000269 
    [FIRST_NAME] => LUIS 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => FERNANDO 
    [a_paterno] => BOCANEGRA 
    [a_materno] => RAMIREZ 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => PERS 
    [email_people] => fercho_114_@hotmail.com ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000270 
    [FIRST_NAME] => SERGIO 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => ENRIQUE 
    [a_paterno] => BOCANEGRA 
    [a_materno] => RAMIREZ 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => INST 
    [email_people] => sebocanegrara@ucq.edu.mx ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000270 
    [FIRST_NAME] => SERGIO 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => ENRIQUE 
    [a_paterno] => BOCANEGRA 
    [a_materno] => RAMIREZ 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => PERS 
    [email_people] => sergioramirez1798@gmail.com ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000292 
    [FIRST_NAME] => ANDREA 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => 
    [a_paterno] => CASTAÑEDA 
    [a_materno] => BASURTO 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => INST 
    [email_people] => ancastanedaba@ucq.edu.mx ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000292 
    [FIRST_NAME] => ANDREA 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => 
    [a_paterno] => CASTAÑEDA 
    [a_materno] => BASURTO 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => LABOR 
    [email_people] => andrea.castaneda@masipro.com.mx ) 
[7] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000292 
    [FIRST_NAME] => ANDREA 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => 
    [a_paterno] => CASTAÑEDA 
    [a_materno] => BASURTO 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => PERS 
    [email_people] => casbas.andrea@gamil.com ) 
[8] => stdClass Object ( 
    [matricula] => 000000340 
    [FIRST_NAME] => AXEL 
    [MIDDLE_NAME] => 
    [a_paterno] => CAZARIN 
    [a_materno] => MINCHACA 
    [estatus] => NUIN 
    [EmailType] => INST 
    [email_people] => axcazarinmi@ucq.edu.mx ) )
```

> Función

```
function getInstitucionalAlumnosSinAccesos()
    {  
        if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
            redirect(base_url().'Auth');
        }
        try {
            $tipo_operacion = 1;
            $elements = $this->Institutional_alumnos_model->getInstitucionalAlumnosSinAccesos();

            if ($tipo_operacion == 1) {
                foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value->EmailType == 'INST') {
                        $matricula = $value->matricula;
//Aquí debería de eliminar los registros que tenga la matricula guardada en la variable $matricula
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
            } //./catch
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo más adecuado sería omitir esos registros desde la consulta, con un `emailType != 'INST'`. De no ser posible, o si quieres continuar con tu código actual, aquí va una propuesta:

Primero hay que crear un arreglo para almacenar las matrículas que deben eliminarse y, después, volver a recorrer los elementos para eliminar los que están dentro del arreglo:

```
function getInstitucionalAlumnosSinAccesos()
    {  
        if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
            redirect(base_url().'Auth');
        }
        try {
            $tipo_operacion = 1;
            $elements = $this->Institutional_alumnos_model->getInstitucionalAlumnosSinAccesos();

            if ($tipo_operacion == 1) {
                // Crear un arreglo de matrículas
                $matriculas = [];
                // Buscar matrículas a eliminar
                foreach($elementos as $key => $value) {
                    // Si el tipo es INST y no se ha agregado
                    if($value->emailType == 'INST' && !in_array($value->matricula, $matriculas)) {
                        // Agregar a arreglo
                        $matriculas[] = $value->matricula;
                    }
                }
                // Recorrer para eliminar
                foreach($elements as $key => $value) {
                    // Si la matrícula está en el arreglo
                    if(in_array($value->matricula, $matriculas)) {
                        // Eliminar elemento por posición
                        unset($elementos[$key]));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        } //./catch
    }
```

Solo ten en cuenta que los índices ya no van a ser consecutivos, si necesitas recorrer el arreglo otra vez, deberá ser nuevamente con `foreach($elements as $key => $value)`, o simplemente con `foreach($elements as $value)` porque ya no necesitas el índice.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que necesito quitarlos por matricula ya que existen mas registros que tienen esa matricula.

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Me parece que si pasas el objeto por referencia lo puedes modificar, si es lo que interesa para este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ♥

Comment: @A.Cedano, no entendí, ¿podrías proporcionar un ejemplo?

Comment: Me refería a hacer algo [como esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329451/29967), ahí `&$value` es pasado por referencia dentro del bucle (por eso la `&`) y puede ser modificado... O bien [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198799/29967). Hay también [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198966/29967) sobre el tema de pasar por referencia o no. Creo que para este caso podría ser útil.

Comment: @A.Cedano, muy interesantes las respuestas, pero mi lógica no alcanza a ver la utilidad de pasar `$value` por referencia en estos dos ciclos. Investigaré para satisfacer mi curiosidad. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @A.Cedano, encontré información muy útil en [esta respuesta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php#answer-3430538): _"So if you're modifying the array in the loop, it's several times faster to use references"_, **Si modificas el arreglo dentro del ciclo**, es varias veces más rápido usar referencias.

Comment: Había leído que pasar por referencia era más rápido, de hecho lo menciono con un enlace en la pregunta que abrí sobre el tema. Pero no hubo mucha atención a ese asunto (una sola respuesta) y yo tampoco seguí profundizando en ello.

Comment: Efectivamente, @A.Cedano, es más rápido si modificas los valores, en este caso, creo que no afecta el rendimiento en el primer ciclo (solo lectura) y quizá habría que probar en el segundo ciclo, pero algo me dice que, en caso de haber diferencia, sería mínima.